# Copying files to an NTFS marks them as "shared" in Vista

Tags: ntfs

I can mount and copy files to an NTFS partition just fine from Ubuntu. However all the folders I copy end up being market as "shared" ("Freigabe" in german) when viewed from Windows Vista side and I have to manually unshare them on Vista.

What is causing the files to be marked as shared and how can I avoid that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

There is a default user mapping between linux uid/gid to Windows user accounts. Also a default creation mask can be defined during mount time.

There should be a ntfs-3g man page available already. My guess is that once you mount the ntfs volume with the 'inherit' option, the created files should inherit the access rights from their parent folder.